# Most efficient way or algo to find shortest path between any two nodes in a graph?

Tags: graph

I have a huge graph of network nodes. I would like to know what is the most efficient algo or technique to obtain the shortest path between any two nodes in the graph?

I have studied an algorithm of "All pair shortest path" but the time complexity is O(V^3) which is worse in my case as the number of nodes is large. How to reduce this complexity?

Comment: Whats the size of the input, number of vertices? number of edges?

Comment: I think you should definitely give a look to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265454/3444956