# Would n calls of Bellman Ford be faster than Floyd-Warshall when finding the shortest distance from each node to each other node?

Tags: shortest-path, floyd-warshall, bellman-ford

Assuming that there are no negative edges.

Floyd-Warshall has a constant runtime of O(V^3). Bellman Ford has a worst case runtime of O(VE), but a best case of O(E).

So running BF for each individual node would have a worst case runtime of O(EV^2) but a best case of O(VE), is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellman Ford will be slower than Floyd-Warshall in almost all cases. If the graph is a tree, then `E = V`, and both will be the same `V^3`. However, its very easy for `E` to be much larger. `E` can be up to `V^2` in the case of a complete graph, where BF on just one node will take just as long as FW on the entire graph.

There's rarely a reason to use BF when Dijkstra's can solve the same problem in `E+VlogV`, which will be faster than `VE` in again all cases other than a simple tree.

Comment: So could the same thing be said about n calls of Dijkstra's?

Comment: Running Dijkstra's for each node will be faster Floyd-Warshall in all cases other than when the graph is close to complete (Specifically, when `E` is appx equal to `V^2`). There's a reason why Dijkstra's algorithm is the famous one. The only time using Dijkstra's isn't the best is when you need negative edges (Where it ends up not working at all).

Comment: @NicholasPipitone thank you for saying this! i've been scratching my head trying to make sense of this whole post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212431/dijkstra-vs-floyd-warshall-finding-optimal-route-on-all-node-pairs.  

to state my reasoning for posterity - if dijkstra's - naively implemented, using an unordered array to keep track of distances takes o(n^2) - performing this once for each node as source (n times)... is... o(n^3).